# String function to extract only ID from URL

Tags: php, string, url

I have this string:

```
solutions.php?id=80d28c22-68d9-11e3-af95-742f689f29f1
```

How can I extract just the part of the id, just the value of the ID, the

```
80d28c22-68d9-11e3-af95-742f689f29f1
```

I tried the substring function of PHP, the problem is I'm still figuring out how to tell it that it's all the way till the end of the string.

This is what I have so far:

```
 $_solutionID = substr($_currentURL, 17, ??);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

`$id = $_GET['id'];`

That should work :)

Comment: Thank you. Very simple, never thought of this.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve that value from the [GET superglobal](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) array: `$_GET['id']`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [$_GET variable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) for your purpose:

```
echo $_GET['id'];
# => 80d28c22-68d9-11e3-af95-742f689f29f1
```

`$_GET` is a superglobal that is available anywhere in a PHP script, and can be used to check the values of query parameters in a URL, i.e. it stores an associative array of all query parameters of the current page URL.

Also, for reference, if you happen to issue a POST request and would like to find the data that was posted to that URL, you can use `$_POST` variable in exactly the same manner as the `$_GET` variable.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to use [parse_url](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.parse-url.php) to extract the query (after the '?') and a regex to extract the id after the 'id='.

```
$parts = parse_url('solutions.php?id=80d28c22-68d9-11e3-af95-742f689f29f1');

$query = $parts['query'];

$matches = array();
if (preg_match('/id=([-0-9a-z]+)/', $query, $matches) {
    return $matches[1];
}
```

Comment: really? `parse_url` and `regex` for this purpose?

Comment: Question was "how to extract a part of a string". @Yisera didn't mentionned that it was the url of the current page and he just wanted to get a GET parameter...